# Como converter std::thread para Handle

Tags: winapi, sfml

Estou tentando fazer funcionar um exemplo de Win32api + SFML para estudar. No entanto, estou com um problema de tipos diferentes.

```cpp
std::thread contentWndThread(ContentThreadMain, hInst);
        SetThreadPriority( contentWndThread.native_handle(), THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL);
```

O erro que o vscode me dá é o seguinte:

```
argument of type "std::thread::native_handle_type" is incompatible with parameter of type "HANDLE"C/C++(167)
```

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido:

````cpp
std::thread contentWndThread(ContentThreadMain, hInst);
        auto handle = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(contentWndThread.native_handle());
        SetThreadPriority( handle, THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL);
    ```
````